# How can I get words from a string, textarea javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, textarea

I've been working on JavaScript and HTML, I have a text area where the user sets a CSV like this:

```
17845    hello     bye    789
```

Now I have `17845,hello,bye,789` and I need to extract the values between the commas. I've tried with index Of, but what if the user sets 2 lines instead of 1, how can I get these words? I have thought of separate them getting the `"\n"`.

Comment: `17845 hello bye 789` if this your text how did you end up with this `17845,hello,bye,789` ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript function split() will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '17845,hello,bye,789';
var words = str.split(',');

console.log(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript split() Function

Answer (score 0):

Split function gives u the array.

```js
var sentence ="hello, 123, tedsfd, demo";
var strArr = sentence.split(',');
$.each(strArr,function(key,value){
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you are facing issues if the user sets comma separated value in multiple lines instead of one... For that use [`trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function to remove all tabs and newline and then use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split`.
It converts strings into arrays, given you provide the delimiter, to separate the string.

```
var userInput = '17845, hello, bye, 789';

data = userInput.split(',');

console.log(data);
//data[0] = '17845'
//data[1] = 'hello'
//data[2] = 'bye'
//...
```